# How to remove dots from numbers?

Tags: php, mysql, formatting, numbers

I have a form formatted with javascript, which makes numbers look like:

10.000 or 2.300

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="price_1" value="2.300">
</form>
```

But i want to store them in mysql without dots. How to remove them?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO prices price_a='price_1' WHERE id ='price_id'");
```

I see money_format and number_format, but its just format the numbers dont remove anything.

Comment: Could you include some code snippets

Comment: Hint: you don't have a number, you have string ;-)

Comment: Is there a reason for storing them without dots? You change the meaning of the value then.

Comment: @cryptic The *numeric value* is unaltered by its formatting.

Comment: @deceze 10.000 != 10000 right?

Comment: @cryptic "Ten thousand" is "ten thousand", however it's formatted. 10000, 10.000, 10,000, "ten thousand", "zehntausend", "一万" are all the same ***numeric value***. Not the same *string value*, no, but if you're interested in the numeric value that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this :

```
str_replace(".", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_replace()` function.

```
echo str_replace(".", "", $value);
```

$value would be 10.000

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_replace like this:

```
$var1 = "10.000";
$var1 = str_replace(".", "", $var1);
```

more info about function is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)